# Can I use location.href to generate the url for a variable?

Tags: javascript, disqus, location-href

I'm adding disqus to my website and I was wondering if there's a way to use the page's url to fill in the variable for `disqus_url`

I know that `window.location.href` will find the url, I just don't know how to use that inside of a function.

This is what I've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var disqus_url = window.location.href;
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: According to the Disqus docs (https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472098-javascript-configuration-variables), you don't need to do this, as disqus_url defaults to window.location.href.  But if you want to do it, the way you are doing it is correct.  What isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. However, `window.location.href` is the default, so you really don't need to provide it.

Note that this will most likely treat `http://example.com/helloworld.html` and `http://example.com/helloworld.html?123` as two different threads.

See https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472098-javascript-configuration-variables#disqus_url

Comment: Awesome, thank you. This might need to be a new question, but if i wanted to use the existing canonical tag, would I do this: `var disqus_url = document.querySelector("link[rel='canonical']").href;`